# Get input data value or dropdown

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to get the value of MwSt field. 
This working fine if the field is text field. 
But when I change it to a select DropDown list then it does not work. 
Any Idea?

```
$("input[data-field='x_MwSt']").change(function() {
var mw = parseFloat($("input[data-field='x_MwSt']").val());
$(this).fields("Total").value(mw);  
 });
```

Comment: Dropdowns do not use the `input` tag, they use `select`, so your selector there needs to be updated if you're using a dropdown.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I see.